# what happens when you expire cookies client side and go server side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies

I expire cookies in client side javascript, and then redirect people to server side node js application.

Unfortunately, when I check req.cookies... server side the cookies that were expired client side are still there. How can I fix this issue to make sure cookies are properly expired before moving to server side?

so cookies are expired client side, but when redirect to server side, and check `req.cookies`, cookie value is still there.

What's happening is that I call `Cookie.expire('access_token');` client side, and check `req.cookies.access_token` server side and the check returns true. Is there a way to be certain client side that the cookie was deleted?

Answer (score 0):

If you are properly expiring cookies client-side, the `req.cookies` object shouldn't contain a valid cookie. Are you sure you are properly expiring them before the AJAX call is sent? To be sure, you should think about building in a callback or a Promise to the function that is expiring the cookies.

A better way to do it may be to only do it server-side. This means instead of expiring the cookie on the client, send a quick AJAX call to the server to expire the cookie in the database. This is a more secure way of expiring cookies, but how you implement it depends on how you're storing your cookies and/or session data

Comment: Is there a way on the client side, to check that the cookie was deleted? what's happening is that I call  `Cookie.expire('access_token');`client side, and check `req.cookies.access_token` server side and the check returns true